# Showing FITS image with 4-D array shape (python)

Tags: python, image, plot, shapes, fits

I downloaded a VLASS fits file and i'm trying to plot it without success.
The problem is, i think, the shape

```
print(image_data.shape)
```

which gives me `(1, 1, 3722, 3722)`.
My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.visualization import astropy_mpl_style
plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)

hdulist = fits.open("vla_test.fits")
hdu = hdulist[0]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(hdu.data[0,0,:,:], cmap='Greys')
plt.colorbar()
```

I don't get any error but image doesn't show off and i get white (void) image.
I tried to download other files from the survey but i get same result.

Comment: The shape has nothing to do with it. You may need to normalize the image.